# ¿Cómo se dice: "nos vemos en lunes" o "nos vemos el lunes"? ¿Por qué?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, artículos, tiempo

No puedo entender reglas básicas del uso "el" y "en" cuando nos referimos a un día de la semana.

Por ejemplo: ¿Sería incorrecto decir "nos vemos en lunes" en vez de "nos vemos el lunes"?. Y en qué caso hay que usar "el" o "en".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo correcto sería decir "nos vemos el lunes", si te estás refiriendo a que nos veremos el próximo lunes.

Decir "nos vemos en lunes", aparte de sonar raro, da a entender que sólo nos vemos los lunes o que nos veremos un lunes, aunque no sea el próximo.

No soy lingüista para poderte dar una explicación sobre tu duda, así que me quedaré por aquí para que alguien más entendido que yo te dé una respuesta más técnica y menos práctica.

Comment: El próximo lunes  o uno en concreto aunque sea más distante pero en el que hayamos quedado por algún motivo.  Por ejemplo puede suceder que dentro de dos lunes pillemos el vuelo a las Bahamas, entonces puedes decir, "nos vemos el lunes"

Comment: Si he entendido bien, por ejemplo: "Lugares para salir en lunes" o "Año común comenzado en lunes". ¿En estos casos "en" se utiliza para indicar "un lunes cualquiera"? ¿Y sería correcto decir "los lunes" en vez de "en lunes" en estos casos?

Comment: @RuslanMukhanov cuando usas _el_ te refieres a uno concreto: _el lunes empieza el nuevo curso_ querrá decir que el próximo lunes esto sucederá. Si dices _el curso empieza en lunes_ quieres destacar el hecho de que sea un día que resulta que es lunes, sin importar la fecha exacta.

Comment: @RuslanMukhanov los lunes hace referencia todos los lunes en general: _Los lunes voy a clase de yoga_ o _no me gustan los lunes_. En tu ejemplo "Lugares para salir en lunes" podrías decir _Lugares para salir los lunes_, de hecho creo que suena mejor. En cambio en la frase "Año común comenzado en lunes" no puedes sustituir "en" por "los".

Answer (score 3):

Siempre que te refieras a días debes usar **el**. En el español no tiene sentido hacer referencia a que estés *dentro de* un dia. **En** es para indicar que "estás dentro de". En español no puedes estar dentro de días pero sí dentro de rangos de días.

> Nos vemos el lunes.
>   
> Nos vemos el día 2.
>   
> Nos vemos en el fin de semana.
>   
> Nos vemos en Enero.